# How to correctly initialize a database using sqflite?

Tags: flutter

I am writing thsi Notes App using sqflite, but when trying to create the database using a function and calling this function within the main, the database does not get created and it remains null. here is the code :

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DBHelper {
  Database? _db;

  Future<void> initializeDatabase() async {
    print('Database is about to be created');
    try {
      final String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'tasks.db');
      _db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          print('creating db ..');
          await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE tasks (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            taskTitle TEXT,
            taskDescription TEXT,
            isCompleted INTEGER
          )
          ''');
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error while initializing database: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<int> addTask(Task task) async {
    print('task is about to be inserted ...');
    return await _db!.insert('tasks', Task.toMap(task));
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> fetchingDataFromDB() async {
    return await _db!.query('tasks');
  }
}

// and here is the main function

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:simple_db_app/controller/bindings.dart';
import 'package:simple_db_app/db/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:simple_db_app/view/home_page.dart';
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DBHelper dbhelper = DBHelper();
  await dbhelper.initializeDatabase();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            name: '/homePage', page: () => HomePage(), binding: TasksBidings())
      ],
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

As the code shows, by passing by the onCreate function that is within the openDatabase i'm expecting the console to print **'creating db ..'**, but i do not get any of that on the console. But the console normally prints **'databse is about to be created'** that is under the initializeDatabase function.

And also in the app when i try to click on a button that calls the insert function it gives me exception saying **(Null check operator used on a null value)** which proves that the database really does not get created.

What is wrong with this please?

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md, you should make sure the directory exists:

`await Directory(databasesPath).create(recursive: true);`

Now regarding the null exception, it's hard to tell without more code. In your sample code, dbhelper is a local variable to the main function and is not passed on to your app widget. Are you creating another instance of DBHelper?

Comment: @d-markey yes, I am creating other DBHelper instances within the taskControoler (I am using Getx as state management) just to access the insert and fetchData functions, using this code **'DBHelper().insert(parameter)'**

Comment: @d-markey after checking if the directory exists and creating it, now it gives me this errror **' Error while initializing database: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.simple_db_app/databases/tasks.db' (OS Error: Not a directory, errno = 20)'**

Comment: If you're using GetX already, you should check thé dependency management features of GetX and register the dbhelper instance from your main function. Then instead of creating new DBHelper instances, simply retrieve it from GetX. For the directory, if it doesn't exist, then just create it!

Comment: i have created the directory then joined it with 'tasks.db' normally, but still the compiler do not pass by the onCreate function ( it prints nothing in the console ). I wonder why

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

```dart
class AppDatabase {
// Singleton instance
  static final AppDatabase _singleton = AppDatabase._();

// Singleton accessor
  static AppDatabase get instance => _singleton;

  // Completer is used for transforming synchronous code into asynchronous code.
  Completer<Database>? _dbOpenCompleter;

  // A private constructor. Allows us to create instances of AppDatabase
  // only from within the AppDatabase class itself.
  AppDatabase._();

  // Database object accessor
  Future<Database> get database async {
    // If completer is null, AppDatabaseClass is newly instantiated, so database is not yet opened
    if (_dbOpenCompleter == null) {
      _dbOpenCompleter = Completer();
      // Calling _openDatabase will also complete the completer with database instance
      _openDatabase();
    }
    // If the database is already opened, awaiting the future will happen instantly.
    // Otherwise, awaiting the returned future will take some time - until complete() is called
    // on the Completer in _openDatabase() below.
    return _dbOpenCompleter!.future;
  }

  Future _openDatabase() async {
    try {
      final databaseFactorySqflite = Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux
          ? getDatabaseFactorySqflite(sqflite_ffi.databaseFactoryFfi)
          : getDatabaseFactorySqflite(sqflite.databaseFactory);
      // Get a platform-specific directory where persistent app data can be stored
      final appDocumentDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      // Path with the form: /platform-specific-directory/demo.db
      final dbPath = join(appDocumentDir.path, 'ExampleDB.db');

      var factory = databaseFactorySqflite;
      var db = await factory.openDatabase(dbPath);

      // Any code awaiting the Completer's future will now start executing
      _dbOpenCompleter!.complete(db);
    } catch (e, st) {
     
    }
  }
}
```

And access with

```dart
  Future<Database> get _db async => await AppDatabase.instance.database;
```